# Showing that increasing N (a parameter) causes the function below to shift to the right

Tags: functions, recreational-mathematics

I've been trying to show that increasing $N$ (where $N\in\{2,3,...\}$) shifts the following function rightward:

$$P(x;N,k):= \frac{k(N-1)e^{-kx}}{\left(1+(N-1)e^{-kx}\right)^2}, \ (k>0).$$

I made a graph in Desmos just in case it's helpful:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fi698ohyds.

**Note/Fun(?) Fact:** For those who are interested, this relates to the "Contest Success Function (CSF) in *differences*" discussed in [Hirschleifer (1989)](http://www.econ.ucla.edu/people/papers/hirshleifer/hirshleifer169.pdf); these are used to model the probability of winning a winner-takes-all "contest" (e.g. a conflict). The function above corresponds to $\frac{\partial}{\partial C_1} p_1(\mathbf{C})\bigg|_{\mathbf{C} = (1,0,...,0)}$, where $\mathbf{C}=(C_1,...,C_N)$ and $p_1$ is as in equation (5) of that paper. Anyway, it's a neat paper, I think :)

Comment: I think you have a typo; there's no N on the right side of the equation.

Comment: I see the intended expression at the Desmos link. Hint: try [shifting the graph to the right](https://www.ck12.org/algebra/vertical-and-horizontal-transformations/lesson/vertical-and-horizontal-transformations-mat-aly/) and doing some algebra to see if it's like increasing $N$.

Comment: Oops! Sorry about that. I'll fix that now. 

Thanks, Mark!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using properties of the exponential function we obtain
$$
(N-1) e^{-kx} = 
e^{\ln(N-1)} e^{-kx} = 
e^{\ln(N-1)-kx} = 
e^{-k \left( x - \ln(N-1) / k \right) }
$$
Therefore
$$
P \left( x;\ N,\ k \right) = 
P \left( \left( x - \tfrac{\ln(N-1)}{k} \right)\!;\ 2,\ k \right)
$$